# C++ error C2228

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'll admit I'm not sure of what I'm doing here, so I am doing a lot of copying sample code from my textbook and replacing with info for my own program... but can tell me what is causing this error?

Car.cpp

```
// Implementation file for the Car class
#include "Car.h"

// This constructor accepts arguments for the car's year 
// and make. The speed member variable is assigned 0.
Car::Car(int carYearModel, string carMake)
{
    yearModel = carYearModel;
    make = carMake;
    speed = 0;
}

// Mutator function for the car year
void Car::setYearModel(int carYearModel)
{
        carYearModel = yearModel;
}

// Mutator function for the car make
void Car::setMake(string carMake)
{
    carMake = make;
}
```

Car.h

```
// Specification file for the Car class
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
private:
    int yearModel; // Car year model
    string make;   // Car make
    int speed;     // Car speed

public:
    Car(int, string); // Constructor

    // Mutators
    void setYearModel(int);
    void setMake(string);

};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "Car.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Create car object
    Car honda(int yearModel, string make);

    // Use mutator functions to update honda object

    honda.setYearModel(2005);
    honda.setMake("Accord");


    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

error C2228: left of '.setYearModel' must have class/struct/union

error C2228: left of '.setMake' must have class/struct/union

Comment: `Car honda(int yearModel, string make)` is seen as a function declaration by the C++ compiler because of regrettable design choices. Try `Car honda(2005, "Accord")` instead (and you can remove the `setYearModel` and `setMake` method calls).

Comment: Also, it's bad practice to have headers with `using` statements in them, but that's another story.

Comment: @zneak: I assume "regrettable design choices" is referring to the most vexing parse... but this isn't ambiguous at all.  That wouldn't be a legal constructor call in any case.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, I find it pointless to allow function declarations in a block. I think the `Car honda(int yearModel, string make)` line shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: @zneak: What about `using`-declarations of functions?  What you're wishing for is actually a huge mess of special cases.

Comment: `Using` declarations are usefully prefixed with `using`. I'm fine with those as they're unambiguous to even barely trained humans. You will most certainly prove me wrong because you know C++ much better than me, but I'm still not sure what couldn't be done if the "normal" function declaration syntax didn't work inside blocks. For the most part, I think this just shifts complexity from the compiler to the language (most vexing parse, `Bar bar()` being a function declaration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `Car honda(int yearModel, string make);`, you're declaring a function named honda that takes an int and a string and returns a Car. To create a Car variable named honda, you need to call the constructor with actual values:

```
Car honda(2005, "Accord");
```